# how to calculate ratio on some condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like following..

```
   date                         item_id
2016-01-19                      [188, 188]
2016-01-23                      [188, 142]
2016-02-05                      [188, 264]
2016-02-06  [273, 248, 191, 167, 238, 191]
2016-02-15                           [320]
2016-02-17                           [286]
2016-02-20                      [164, 317]
```

In the above I want to calculate a ratio of `No of times the item_id got repeated on different dates / no of unique item_id` So in above scenario `item_id 188` repeated 3 times on 3 different days so the ratio will be 
`3/no of unique item_id` `3/13`

code to create a dataframe

```
buyer_id item_id        date
261_23     188  2016-01-19
261_23     188  2016-01-19
261_23     188  2016-01-23
261_23     142  2016-01-23
261_23     188  2016-02-05
261_23     264  2016-02-05
261_23     273  2016-02-06
261_23     248  2016-02-06
261_23     191  2016-02-06
261_23     167  2016-02-06
261_23     238  2016-02-06
261_23     191  2016-02-06
261_23     320  2016-02-15
261_23     286  2016-02-17
261_23     164  2016-02-20
261_23     317  2016-02-20

df.groupby(['date','buyer_id'])['item_id'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of the union of all unique items is

```
unique_items = set().union(*df.item_id.apply(set))
```

The number of appearances of each item is

```
num_appearances = [df.item_id.apply(lambda s: k in s).sum() for k in unique_items]
```

Therefore, the following will create a dictionary mapping each item to the ratio you asked:

```
dict((k, n / float(len(unique_items))) \
    for (k, n) in zip(unique_items, num_appearances))
```

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': range(5), 
    'item_id': [[188, 188], [188, 142], [188, 264], [273, 248, 191, 167, 238, 191], [320]]})

unique_items = set().union(*df.item_id.apply(set))
>>> unique_items
{142, 167, 188, 191, 238, 248, 264, 273, 320}

num_appearances = [df.item_id.apply(lambda s: k in s).sum() for k in unique_items]
>>> num_appearances
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]

>>> dict((k, n / float(len(unique_items))) \
    for (k, n) in zip(unique_items, num_appearances))
{142: 0.1111111111111111,
 167: 0.1111111111111111,
 188: 0.33333333333333331,
 191: 0.1111111111111111,
 238: 0.1111111111111111,
 248: 0.1111111111111111,
 264: 0.1111111111111111,
 273: 0.1111111111111111,
 320: 0.1111111111111111}
```

Comment: It gives me `num_appearances` as `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`  but `188` has 3 entries

Comment: @Neil Added the DataFrame + code on which I tried it, and you can see it doesn't output 1s uniformly. If you post the exact code that creates your DataFrame (*not* the prinout in your question), I can run it too. As it stands, I can't really tell what is the difference between your DataFrame and mine.

Comment: it returns me final output as `{'142': 0.083333333333333329,
 '164': 0.083333333333333329,
 '167': 0.083333333333333329,
 '188': 0.083333333333333329,
 '191': 0.083333333333333329,
 '238': 0.083333333333333329,
 '248': 0.083333333333333329,
 '264': 0.083333333333333329,
 '273': 0.083333333333333329,
 '286': 0.083333333333333329,
 '317': 0.083333333333333329,
 '320': 0.083333333333333329}`

Comment: @Neil Your second comment is consistent with your first - it decided that each item appeared once.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It's working with *your* DataFrame on my system.

Comment: Was doing it wrong.. Thanks a lot for your answer.. really appreciated :)